# package name is not loading in DDMS

Tags: android, package, ddms

i am developing an android app and also using the database, I have given one package name at the start of my project and i wanted to integrate my project with other but the other project also had the same name so i have to change my package name in order to differentiate my project with the other.  now the problem is that in the integrated project the package name is not loaded.Also in manifest i have given as follows

```
<activity android:name="com.android.game.PartThree" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity> etc....
```

can any one tell me where i am going wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by not loading ? ant error?

Comment: its not found in file explorer

Comment: make sure your package name and class name is proper ?

Comment: app force closes when i click my part which i have integrated other part works fine

Comment: app force closes then see logcat and put it in question

Comment: hi i got the error actually i have not called one of the methods.thank you all for your comments..